# Can a stack overflow happen for any other reason that recursion?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow

I'm getting a stack overflow exception for a segment of code that doesn't seem to be able to produce a stackoverflow... It looks like this:

```
public String WriteToFile(XmlDocument pDoc, String pPath)
{
  string source = "";
  string seq = "";
  string sourcenet = "";

  XmlNodelist sourceNode = pDoc.GetElementsByTagName(XmlUtils.Nodes.Source);
  source = sourceNode.Item(0).InnerText;

  XmlNodelist sqList= pDoc.GetElementsByTagName(XmlUtils.Nodes.Seq);
  seq = sqList.Item(0).InnerText;

  XmlNodelist sourceNets = pDoc.GetElementsByTagName(XmlUtils.Nodes.SourceNets);
  sourcenet = sourceNets.Item(0).InnerText;

  string fileName = Folders.GetMyFileName(source, seq, sourcenet);
  string fullPath = Path.Combine(pPath, fileName);

  pDoc.Save(pFullPathFile);  <--- Stackoverflow is raised here

  return pFullPathFile; 
}
```

There are no recursive calls, if you examine the call stack it has a depth of 2 before going to "external code" (which I'm guessing is not that external but part of the framework that starts the thread, which has debugging turn off).

¿Is there anyway the exception can be risen because anything other than a recursive call? It does ALWAYS fails in the pDoc.Save method call... and pDoc isn't actually that big... more like 32KB of data...

Comment: can you post real code?  I don't see where pFullPathFile comes from in this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A stack overflow exception can occur any time that the stack exceeds it's maximum size.  This is mostly commonly done with by ...

- Having a deeply nested stack which is not recursive.  Think of event storms where event A leads to event B which leads to event C all of which have handlers that deeply grow the stack.
- Having a shallow stack which occurs after some large stack allocations

Answer (score 4):

Stack overflow simply means you have exhausted the stack, it doesn't need to be caused by recursion. Of course, because recursion utilizes the stack, it is often the cause of a stack overflow exception, but it doesn't need to be.

That being said, with the information you provided, it doesn't sound like there should be anything causing a stack overflow in the code you provided.

Threads in C# have a 1MB stack by default, but you can [create a new thread with a smaller stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cykbwz4.aspx). Do you create threads yourself in this program, and are you setting the stack size ?

Also, have a look at the external code section (right click where it says External Code in the Call Stack window, choose "Show external code"). See if something looks wrong, is the framework for some reason going through a lot of method calls to do the save ?

Comment: ASP.NET has a different default.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a recursive call.

`pDoc.Save()` calls `WriteTo(XmlWriter w)` on the document, which calls `WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)`.

This then calls `WriteTo(XmlWriter w)` on the all the nodes at the root level, which will contain one element node (possibly also some comments, whitespace, processing instructions, a document declarataion...).

On that element, this will cause it to write its tag ('<', element name, and then any attributes) followed by calling `WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)` which calls `WriteTo(XmlWriter w)` on every child element, which calls `WriteContentTo(XmlWriter w)`, and so on and so on.

Hence this is indeed recursive in how each element calls the same method on its child elements, and with a sufficiently deep document on sufficiently small stack space (default is 1MB on most applications, but 256KB on ASP.NET), you'll have a stack overflow.

For the record, you can also have a stack overflow without recursion as long as you burn through your stack space one way or another. `stackalloc` is a great way to find yourself doing this while only a few calls deep.

If you're in trouble due to this recursion, then remember that the implementation of `WriteTo` is essentially (manually inlining `WriteContentTo` into it):

```
w.WriteStartElement(this.Prefix, this.LocalName, this.NamespaceURI);
if (this.HasAttributes)
{
    XmlAttributeCollection attributes = this.Attributes;
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.Count; i++)
    {
        attributes[i].WriteTo(w);
    }
}
if (this.IsEmpty)
{
    w.WriteEndElement();
}
else
{
  for (XmlNode node = this.FirstChild; node != null; node = node.NextSibling)
  {
    node.WriteTo(w);
  }
    w.WriteFullEndElement();
}
```

Replace this with an iterative version, and you won't overflow the stack. Of course if you've somehow managed to put the document into a condition where it's got an element that's an ancestor to itself (does XmlDocument protect against that? I don't know off the top of my head), then it'll turn a stack-overflow into an infinite loop, which if anything is worse.

Answer (score 0):

In some languages/runtimes a stack overflow *can* happen because of large memory allocations that are unrelated to the call stack itself. It's entirely possible that the 'external code' (I assume the framework) is running either into that situation or has actually a classic recursion overflow problem you can't see because you can't necessarily debug into it.